# How to create a native ios app with offline data + sync

Tags: ios, json

I want to create a native application which will get data from json and store it offline (offline storage) for later access. This is a resorts listing app, so it might have updates on the existing records or new records from time to time.

Example: Mashable on iPad

Comment: What did you end up going with?

Comment: i ended up using jquery mobile and phonegap :) ..

Answer (score 3):

RestKit allows you to cache data locally via CoreData and query it via JSON from the server.

http://restkit.org

From their site:

> Core Data support. Building on top of the object mapping layer,
>   RestKit provides integration with Apple’s Core Data framework. This
>   support allows RestKit to persist remotely loaded objects directly
>   back into a local store, either as a fast local cache or a primary
>   data store that is periodically synced with the cloud. RestKit can
>   populate Core Data associations for you, allowing natural property
>   based traversal of your data model. It also provides a nice API on top
>   of the Core Data primitives that simplifies configuration and querying
>   use cases.